# ¿Como restar una hora determinada con la hora del sistema en php?

Tags: php, datetime, php5, time

¿Como puedo hacer que la variable $total me de un resultado en formato de hora?
Esta ahora con este codigo lo unico que logro es restar las horas, pero no los minutos, y solo me muestra un numero. ejemplo: 07:45 - 03:35 = 4. quisiera que en vez de darme 4 me de algo como: 03:10.

```
$fin = '07:45';               
$hora = date("H:i");  
$total = $fin - $hora;

echo "EL evento empezara en $total";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una función simple debería de bastar para la resta de horas:

**Realiza lo siguiente:**

```
$hora_actual=date("H:i");
$fin = '07:45'; 
$resultado=date("H:i:s",strtotime("00:00") +strtotime($fin) - strtotime($hora_actual) );
echo $resultado;
```

Esto debería de funcionar, pero ten en cuenta que `date("H:i")`, saca la hora actual según la zona horaria de tu servidor, así que esa configuración de la dejo a vos.

Recordad también que solo funcionaria en resta de `horas` y **no tomaria en cuenta las fechas**.

Comment: Me funciona a la perfección, Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear dos objetos `DateTime`, uno con la hora fija `07:45` y otro con la hora actual.

Luego usas `diff` para calcular la diferencia entre los dos objetos, haciendo cálculos sobre los diferentes grupos de diferencias que hay en el objeto que te arrojará `diff`.

Por ejemplo:

```
$dateStart = new DateTime("07:45:00");
$dateEnd   = new DateTime();
$dateInterval = $dateEnd->diff($dateStart);

$strResult = sprintf(
    '%d:%02d:%02d', //formato de salida
    ($dateInterval->d * 24) + $dateInterval->h, //horas
    $dateInterval->i, //minutos
    $dateInterval->s  //segundos
);
echo "El evento empezará en $strResult";
```

Usar `diff` es la mejor manera de calcular diferencias entre fechas, pues te arroja un objeto completo con todo tipo de diferencias. Para que te hagas una idea, esta es toda la información que habrá en el objeto `$dateInterval` del código de más arriba. Te permitirá saber, si fuera necesario, no sólo cuántas horas/minutos/segundos hay entre dos fechas, sino también cuántas semanas, meses, años ... y más información.

```
object(DateInterval)#3 (15) {
  ["y"]=>
  int(0)
  ["m"]=>
  int(0)
  ["d"]=>
  int(0)
  ["h"]=>
  int(3)
  ["i"]=>
  int(5)
  ["s"]=>
  int(50)
  ["weekday"]=>
  int(0)
  ["weekday_behavior"]=>
  int(0)
  ["first_last_day_of"]=>
  int(0)
  ["invert"]=>
  int(0)
  ["days"]=>
  int(0)
  ["special_type"]=>
  int(0)
  ["special_amount"]=>
  int(0)
  ["have_weekday_relative"]=>
  int(0)
  ["have_special_relative"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

Comment: Me ha funcionado el otro, el problema con tu codigo es que si actualmente son las 10:40 y el evento empezara mañana a las 07:45 dice que faltan 3 horas, porque cuenta la diferencia mas cercana que hay entre ambas horas, pero no las esta restando.

Comment: @LuisCesar no entiendo bien ese nuevo planteamiento. Sin embargo el código funcionaría si le pasas datos reales a cada objeto creado. Para el caso concreto que dices, si usas estos valores en cada objeto: `$dateStart = new DateTime("2018-06-14 07:45:00");
$dateEnd   = new DateTime("10:40");` el resultado sería: `El evento empezará en 21:05:00`.