# Campos Calculados

Tags: php, laravel

Trabajo con laravel 5.5

Tengo una duda, tengo estos 3 campos:

Hora Inicio:

```
{!! Form::myInput('time', 'hora_inicio', 'Hora inicio: ', ['required']) !!}
```

Hora Final

```
{!! Form::myInput('time', 'hora_final', 'Hora final: ', ['required']) !!}
```

Tiempo Total

```
{!! Form::myInput('text', 'tiempo_total', 'Tiempo Total: ', ['required', 'readonly' => 'readonly']) !!}
```

Quisiera saber como hacer para que la hora final se le reste la hora  inicial, y se auto calcule en el campo tiempo_total, para poder guardarlo en una BD, Y pues obviamente, que la hora inicial no sea mayor a la hora final.

Gracias por leerme.

Comment: Hola puedes tomar como referencia lo siguiente: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/172757/como-restar-una-hora-determinada-con-la-hora-del-sistema-en-php

Comment: Gracias bro, lo mirare.

Comment: vale, espero te sirva

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si al usuario final no le sirve el dato de "tiempo total" sugeriría ocultarlo del formulario. Para hacer lo que quieres en PHP puedes utilizar la librería de "Carbon" que ya viene incluida en Laravel.

Importas la clase;

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

En tu función pones lo siguiente:

```
public function unaFuncion(Request $request){
     $hora_inicial = new Carbon($request->hora_inicial);
     $hora_final = new Carbon($request->hora_final);

     $duracion = $hora_final->diff($hora_inicial)->format('%H:%i:%s');  
}
```

Se debe de aprovechar al máximo lo que ya trae el framework.

Ahora que si quieres mantener el input de tiempo total, puedes calcular la diferencia con javascript (usando jQuery y moment.js) de la siguiente forma:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    calcularTiempo();
});

function calcularTiempo(){
    //Tomando en cuenta que solo hay un input con esos nombres en el formulario
    $('input[name=hora_inicio], input[name=hora_final]').on('change', function(e){
    var valorInicio = $.trim($("input[name=hora_inicio]").val());
    var valorFinal = $.trim($("input[name=hora_final]").val());

    //Comprobar que si haya valores en ambos campos para poder validar y calcular
    if(valorInicio != '' && valorFinal != ''){
       //Validar el formato correcto del tiempo (HH:mm - 22:05)
       if(!validarHMS(valorInicio) || !validarHMS(valorFinal)){
          //alertar al usuario que los datos no son válidos
          return false;
       }
      //crear formato de fecha

      tiempoInicial = moment(valorInicio, "hh:mm");
      tiempoFinal = moment(valorFinal, "hh:mm");

      var total = moment(tiempoFinal.diff(tiempoInicial)).format("hh:mm"); 

      $('#tiempo_total').val(total);
    } 



});

}

function validarHMS(valor) {
        var esValido = /^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-4]):([0-5][0-9])(:[0-5][0-9])?$/.test(valor);

        return esValido;
    }
```

Si recomiendo ampliamente la adición de la librería `moment.js` para cuestiones de manejo de fechas y hora, te facilita mucho las cosas.

De igual forma, si conservas el input de tiempo total en tu formulario, deberás de recalcular en PHP porque cualquiera podría modificar el input.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu ayuda, pero, digamos que no entiendo como hacer que el campo muestre la diferencia de horas, ya entiendo los calculos que hace y como los realiza, pero haria falta el ajax ?

Comment: @OmarNoa Listo, ya actualicé la respuesta.

Comment: Ya agrege la libreria y todo lo que me dijiste, pero creo que me hace falta enviarlo a ese campo tiempo_total